# how to access other columns of an android sqlite database when i have info from one column's record

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite, path

I have an activity where it shows an image from the phone`s sd card, and I have the path of the image that was passed from another activity to the current activity as an intent extra, example: //mnt/sdcard/DCIM/pic05.png

the path is stored in the database under the column named _data and there are other columns for each record that are there, like description and _display_name, how do I access these?

for example I have the path like the one shown above, pic05.png and I want to show the _display_name in a textview for that pic,  that is what I am trying to find out how to do.

Comment: To retrieve an information from a sql database you use a select query. Please follow this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html to learn how to acheive that.

Comment: i noticed the newer version of code in the tutorial: Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;     that is different from what i have been using, older code that is deprecated like the managedQuery(),  is there any problem mixing the two styles older and new code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple SQL would do, based on a table:

```
CREATE TABLE pictures
( fileName TEXT NOT NULL,
  displayName TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY pictures_pk( fileName ) );
```

You could simply:

```
SELECT displayName
  FROM pictures
 WHERE fileName = ?
```

Or in Java:

```
SQLiteDatabase db...
String displayName;
Cursor c = db.query( "pictures", null, "fileName=pic01.png", null, null, null, null );
c.moveToFirst();
if( !c.isAfterLast() )
    displayName = c.getString(1);
```

This is very simplified. You'll need to pass the columns you want and use proper column-index when you access the cursor.

Comment: what do i put for database name,  like SQLiteDatabase db;  and you put "db" for the name of the database when using the query method.  however what do you put for the name when using the query method on the built in database that is used by the android system when storing pictures on the external SD card.  on my phone the file is called external7e47564.db or just external7e47564 and the table name is images.